# Creating two dfs from the data frame list

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a list of data frames

```
a <- data.frame(V1=c("Dzienna",4.12,"czas", "2022-01-01 00:00:00", "2022-01-01 01:00:00"), 
                V2=c(NA,NA,"Moc", 0.13, 1.15)
                )
b <- data.frame(V1=c("Dzienna",5.17,"czas", "2022-02-01 00:00:00", "2022-02-01 01:00:00"), 
                V2=c(NA,NA,"Moc", 0.18, 2.05)
)
L1 <- list(a, b)
L1
```

I want to get two dataframes that will look like below

```
  Dzienna.prod       Data
1         4.12 2022-01-01
2         5.17 2022-02-01


                 Czas  Moc
1 2022-01-01 00:00:00 0.13
2 2022-01-01 01:00:00 1.15
3 2022-02-01 00:00:00 0.18
4 2022-02-01 01:00:00 2.05
```

I am trying to achieve the goal using lapply and do.call, but so far without success

Comment: What is the pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every df has this pattern, you can transform each dataframe in the lists to the format you need. Also, from the `tidyverse` tag I assume I can use dplyr functions.

For df1 the only pattern I see is the numeric value originating from row 2, column 1 and the date originating from row 4 column 1

```
f1 <- function(df) {
  data.frame(t(df[c(2, 4), 1])) %>% 
    mutate(X2 =  as.Date(X2)) %>% 
    rename(Dzienna.prod = X1, Data = X2)
}

df1 <- bind_rows(lapply(L1, f1))
> df1
  Dzienna.prod       Data
1         4.12 2022-01-01
2         5.17 2022-02-01
```

For `f1` I assume that the column `Data` is just the date coming from the datetimes in the dataframes.

The only pattern I recognize for the second dataframe is that it comes from the 4th and 5th row of the dataframes in the list.

```
f2 <- function(df) {
  df[4:nrow(L1[[1]]),] %>% rename(Czas = V1, Moc=V2)
}


df2 <- bind_rows(lapply(L1, f2))
> df2
                 Czas  Moc
1 2022-01-01 00:00:00 0.13
2 2022-01-01 01:00:00 1.15
3 2022-02-01 00:00:00 0.18
4 2022-02-01 01:00:00 2.05
```